# If Kilometer above 100 kilometer, pay 0.20 cent extra per kilometer

Tags: c#, winforms

If the kilometer is above 100 kilometer then the totalprice need to increment with 0.20 cent per every 1 kilometer. How do i do this? I have no idea. I work with Windows Forms Visual Studio 2019. I have something but it's not complete. The totalprice should also include the every 0.20 cent per kilometer.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string typeCar = comboBox1.Text;
    int car= 0;
    int days = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    int totalKM = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);

    if (typeCar == "A")
    {
        car= 50;
    } 
    else if (typeCar == "B")
    {
        car = 75;
    }
    else
    {
        car = 100;
    }
            
    MessageBox.Show("De totale prijs wordt " + car * days + " euro");            
}
```

Comment: Did you step through your code in a debugger?

Comment: Control question: Do you mean per kilometer *above* 100 km, or for all kilometers, the 100 km is just the trigger? As an example, if the distance is 101km, do you pay 1*0.20 or 101*0.20?

Comment: Your title isn't a programming problem, its a homework title. Stackoverflow isnt a substitute for teachers, or school, or research. If you choose to use this place, use it in a way that its intended, as a knowledge base of programming problem, which means you will need to think about your problem in programming terms, this in turn doesn't include things like "*If Kilometer above 100 kilometer, pay 0.20 cent extra per kilometer*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’d suggest you to store the total price in a separate variable. That way, you can check for the `totalKM` value and add to that total price in that case:

```
decimal totalPrice = car * days;

if (totalKM > 100)
{
    totalPrice += totalKM * .2;
}

MessageBox.Show("De totale prijs wordt " + totalPrice + " euro");
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your time, this is what i needed.

Comment: I read it more as `if (totalKM > 100) totalPrice += (totalKM - 100) * 0.2;`

Answer (score 1):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int days = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    int totalKM = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
    string typeCar = comboBox1.Text;

    (string,decimal)[] priceTable = {("A", 50.0m),("B",75.0m),(typeCar, 100.0m)};
    decimal price = priceTable.First(p => p.Item1 == typeCar).Item2;
    price = price * days + (totalKM>100?(totalKM-100)*0.2m:0);
            
    MessageBox.Show($"De totale prijs wordt {price:N2} euro");            
}
```

See it work here:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/4UXhK3